# Is this external drive (verbatim 47564 320gb) recognized by Linux?

Tags: hardware, disk, external-hdd

I'm buying this drive:

http://www.techfuels.com/hard-disk/8068-verbatim-47564-320gb-external-usb-hard-drive.html

because of transition from Windows 7 to Linux (Mint/Ubuntu) and I want to save my files from Windows 7 (movies, pictures etc.)

Does anyone know something about Linux's support for this piece of hardware?

Answer (score 3):

Any recent USB hard drive will implement the [USB Mass Storage Device class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass-storage_device_class), which is supported out-of-the-box under Ubuntu. (This support is in the Linux kernel itself from v2.4, so any distribution from the past decade or so will support it.)

If you want to be able to read and write files to the same filesystem under both Windows and Linux, you should format it as NTFS.